# Trying to read an excel file using poi apache library

Tags: java, excel, apache

I am trying to read an excel file using poi apache library. I tried different types of code but still i am getting the same error with all of my codes. I do not know why this error is coming.

You can download POI apache library from this link:
https://poi.apache.org/download.html

Here is my code to read an excel file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

/**
 *
 * @author Pacer
 */
public class ReadExcelDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("book.xlsx"));

            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext())
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                    switch (cell.getCellType())
                    {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            file.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the error i am getting:

```
Working Directory = E:\NetBeansProjects\Project24\CoverageCodetool

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
    at coveragecodetool.ReadExcelDemo.main(ReadExcelDemo.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing  `xmlbeans` apache library in your classpath.

Add xmlbeans to your classpath and everything will work.

The library itself can be downloaded [here](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/sourceAndBinaries/).

The general algorithm of resolving `NoClassDefFoundException` is the following:

1. search for the library that uses the class mentioned in the Exception. I prefer [this service](http://grepcode.com)
2. add the library to your classpath
3. try to run the code and see if the problem still persists.
4. repeat from step one

Comment: It says org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException, what does that mean?

Comment: ok. I added import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException; as suggested, i get some errors:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/main/ThemeDocument

Comment: ok now i added one more library with xmlbeans and poi ooxml schemas, now it is running fine. thank you!

Comment: added the general resolve algorithm to my answer. And yeah, please accept the answer